# sequential continuous and filter convergence ,continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f:X\to Y$ be the map between two topological space, sequential continuous does not always imply continuous,but only in sequential space.

Here is another version of continuous that is continuous in the filter of neighborhood.I was wondering does convergence in filter implies $f$ be continuous

I found it holds but need more concept the theorem stated as below:

> a function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff for every filter $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ if $\mathcal{F} \to x$ then $f_{\star}\mathcal{F}\to f(x)$

Where $f_*\mathcal{F} = \{B\subset Y\mid \text{exist} A \in \mathcal{F} \text{with } f(A) \subset B\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick an open $U\subseteq Y$, we want to show that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

Pick some $x\in f^{-1}(U)$. Clearly $F_x\to x$, where $F_x$ is the filter of nbhds of $x$, so $f_\ast F_x\to f(x)$ by assumption, which means that for some $V\in F_x$, we have $f(V)\subseteq U$. But then $V\subseteq f^{-1}(U)$, and since $x$ was arbitrary in $f^{-1}(U)$ we have that $f^{-1}(U)$ contains a neighbourhood of each of its points, that is $f^{-1}(U)$ is open and $f$ is continuous.